# How to update column in database ONLY / WHEN value in DB is smaller then the NEW value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update column "idleTime" every few  minute with this query. I would like to update it ONLY in case that the value in DB is smaller!

```
    INSERT INTO
          bl_statistics (id, date, idleTime) 
    VALUES
          ("", DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d"), "1.01234") 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
          idleTime=if(VALUES(idleTime) < 1.01234, VALUES(idleTime), "1.01234");
```

No matter what, value ALWAYS get overwriten, Am I missing something or it is impossible to update values in such way?

Comment: `VALUES(idleTime)` refers to the new value you're assigning, not the existing value in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is quite right but I think you have not specified a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column `date`.

To do that,

```
ALTER TABLE bl_statistics ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE(date)
```

And execute this statement,

```
INSERT INTO bl_statistics(`id`, `date`, `idleTime`)
VALUES(NULL, '2013-05-30 00:00:00', 2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idleTime = IF(idleTime < 2, 2, idleTime)
```

Here's a link of fully working demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87bab/1

oh, one more thing, do not store date as string but instead store it as `DATETIME` or `DATE`.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to *update* the value, why are you using `insert`?

```
update bl_statistics
    set idleTime = 1.01234,
        date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d")
    where idleTime < 1.01234 and id = ''
```

Comment: Well it has to create new row for new day :(

Comment: @ProDraz . . . Have you considered inserting all the values and just choosing the ones you want when you query the table?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm new to MySQL, if you know any other solution please let me know, but with just UPDATE I can't create new row when that's needed :(

Comment: @ProDraz . . . Correct.  Just insert all the values into the table.  When you go to query it, choose the largest value per day.

Comment: I'm doing 1000 queries per day, while 1 row = 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with an `UPDATE` statement.

Using your example, try something like this:

```
update bl_statistics
set date = current_date(),
  idleTime = greatest(idleTime,"1.01234")
where id = ""
```

Comment: I'm familiar with UPDATE statement, but I need to create new row if key does not match (date)...